# What does "menace" mean?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've got a [Weldfast Monitor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWeldfast%20Monitor%5d), an *Artifact Creature — Lizard*. For one mana, it "gains menace".  **What does "gains menace" mean?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menace means "This creature can't be blocked except by two or more creatures."

This means when it comes to blocking, your opponent either assigns 2+ creatures to block it or none at all.

You'll see its reminder text on cards from other editions like [Insolent Neonate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInsolent%20Neonate%5d), but it looks like none of the Menace cards in Kaladesh had reminder text for the ability. Menace became a keyword ability during the *Origins* set.